# Как посмотреть название class с помощью js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как возможно скопировать в переменную название класса пренадлежащего body.

Нашел вот такое решение но оно возвращает:

> [object HTMLBodyElement]

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var BlockName = document.querySelector("body");
```

Вот так выглядит HTML

```
<body class="fp-viewing-whatWeDo-0" style="overflow: visible; height: initial;">
```

Скопировать необходимо fp-viewing-whatWeDo-0.

Comment: let a = BlockName.getAttribute('class');

Comment: let a = document.body.className;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да... запросили HTML-элемент, получили HTML-элемент)) 

В хроме, если записать `console.dir( element )` можно еще в консоли посмотреть все свойства этого элемента. Правый клик на странице, в открывшемся меню - Inspect:

( можно проверить тут → https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/54nf86mz/ )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А значения всех этих свойств можно достать через "точку". `.className` возвращает строку, а `.classList` - массив. Хотя `className == classList.value`

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");

console.log( body.className );

console.log( body.classList[0] );
console.log( body.classList[1] );
console.log( body.classList.value );
```

```html
<body class="fp-viewing-whatWeDo-0 test-class"></body>
```

P.s. `.getAttribute('class')` vs `.className` — разница в том, что первое достаёт то, что реально написано в атрибуте в HTML-коде в момент запроса... а второе - то, что содержится в JS-свойстве. В данном случае нет разницы, т.к. при смене класса, изменения происходят и тут, и там. А в других случаях идет рассинхрон - в атрибуте может быть одно, а в JS - другое ( например .onclick vs getAttribute('onclick') )

P.s.-2 body же не создаётся динамически... Поэтому вместо того, чтобы при скролле каждый раз пересоздавать переменную и искать body, можно так:

```
var bodyClass = document.querySelector("body").className;
window.onscroll = function() { 
  console.log( bodyClass );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать специальное свойство [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```
document.querySelector("body").classList
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
let a = document.body.className;
```